# SVG: Text centerd differently in FF and Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-4

I have the following SVG content

```
<svg height="64" width="64" class="ng-star-inserted">
  <rect rx="10" ry="10" style="fill:silver;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" x="0" y="0" height="64" width="64">
  </rect>
  <text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">
 missing 
  </text>
</svg>
```

which makes essentially a grey box with some text. The text should be centered - vertically and horizontally. I place the whole thing in a Bootstrap 4 structure next to a input field (type `file`). But somehow the center of the text in the SVG seems to be calculated differently depending on the browser.

The whole code looks like:

```
<li class="media">
  <div class="mr-3">
    <svg height="64" width="64" class="ng-star-inserted">
      <rect rx="10" ry="10" style="fill:silver;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" x="0" y="0" height="64" width="64">
      </rect>
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">
     missing 
      </text>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">{{getLabel()}}</h5>
    <input class="form-control-file" type="file" type="file" >
  </div>
</li>
```

as seen in the picture the text `missing` is on the left side (FF) just above the supposed center. I can change the center alignment of `50%` to `32px` which would be perfect for Chrome but for `FF` it should be `34px`. I guess FF starts calculating for the `x` the whole row height and and not image-start.

[image: Differenct rending in different browser]

Changing `alignment-baseline="middle"` to `center`, `hanging` `baseline` did not fix the problem either.

Is there a way to fix it so it works in both browser identically?

Comment: In my experience, there's not much you can do about this, spare looking at the User-Agent on the server and returning a slightly different file to Firefox browsers.

Comment: the answer below seems like magic - it works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `dominant-baseline="middle"` and edit your code like this:

```
 <text alignment-baseline="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" text- 
    anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">
     missing 
 </text>
```

[Link to documenttion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline)

Here's the [codepen snippet](https://codepen.io/royestone/pen/PBbqKv) that I tested in both Chrome and Firefox.