# How to adjust the size of the multiline text in SVG and position it in the middle

Tags: html, svg, text

I have a text that I want to adjust it to the size of svg container and position it in the middle (horizontally and vertically). I am looking for relative way, not absolute. So far I have tried putting the text inside svg and adjust it with viewBox attribute and also the transform: scale function.

Is there any standard way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

With the help of commentators I was able to put the text in the middle of the svg container. Thank you!

However, I am still unable to put multiline text in the middle. The second code snippet is the farthest I came to the solution.

Working code for one line text:

```
<svg width="890" height="500"overflow="hidden;">
<g>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="542" height="495" fill="#6fdd6f"></rect>
  <svg x="0" y="0" width="542" height="495" viewBox="0 0 100 100">      
      <text  alignment-baseline="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">TXT</text>
  </svg>
</g>
</svg>
```

Code with multiline that needs to be adjusted to center:

```
<svg width="890" height="500"overflow="hidden;">
<g>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="542" height="495" fill="#6fdd6f"></rect>
  <svg x="0" y="0" width="542" height="495" viewBox="0 0 100 100">      
      <text alignment-baseline="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" >
      <tspan x="50%" y="50%">TXT</tspan>
      <tspan dy="1em" x="50%" y="50%">more TXT</tspan>
      <tspan dy="2em" x="50%" y="50%">end of TXT</tspan>
      </text>
  </svg>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: you put it in the middle [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424799/svg-text-centerd-differently-in-ff-and-chrome)

Comment: I would use `text-anchor="middle"`and `dominant-baseline:middle` also your text may need an `x` and an `y` attributes where the x and y values are the coordinates of the center. You may use the `getComputedTextLength` to get the text length.